# How to use SQL to update many triggers statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Sorry, My English is not well.

Our database has many triggers that use `getdate()`, and I create a user-defined function named `udf_TranUTCDate()`.

Now I need to update all the `getdate()` to `select dbo.udf_TranUTCDate()` for these triggers.

This is the search statement that I can find triggers need to update

```
select
    so.name as tri_name,
    so2.name as table_name,
    sc.text as tri_content,
    so.xtype
from 
    sysobjects so
inner join 
    syscomments sc on so.id = sc.id --and so.xtype='TR'
inner join 
    sysobjects so2 on so.parent_obj = so2.id
where 
    sc.text like '%getdate()%'
```

and this is what I write to update these triggers

```
update sc
set sc.text = replace(sc.text, 'getdate()', '(select dbo.udf_TranUTCDate())')
from sysobjects so
inner join syscomments sc on so.id=sc.id --and so.xtype='TR'
inner join sysobjects so2 on so.parent_obj = so2.id
where sc.text like '%getdate()%'
```

but I get an error from SQL Server:

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 4

Is there any way to resolve my problem?

Comment: Is the error message "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed"?

Comment: You **CANNOT** just update the definition of the trigger in the system catalogs. Those system catalogs are **read-only**. If you need to update your trigger, you have to issue an `ALTER TRIGGER ......` SQL command with the complete trigger code

Comment: You can change your query so it spits out `ALTER TRIGGER` statements, or you can leverage [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) to do it for you -- import the database, perform a search/replace across everything, save the files with triggers and generate an update script.